# Create new array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [movies] => WP_Post_Type Object
        (
            [name] => movies
            [label] => Movies
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Popular Movies
                    [singular_name] => Movie
                    [add_new] => Add New
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Movie
                )

            [description] => Movie news and reviews
        )

    [portfolio] => WP_Post_Type Object
        (
            [name] => portfolio
            [label] => Portfolio
            [labels] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => New Portfolio Items
                    [singular_name] => Portfolio
                    [add_new] => Add New
                    [add_new_item] => Add New Portfolio
                )

            [description] => Portfolio news and reviews
        )


       [fruits] => WP_Post_Type Object
            (
                [name] => fruits
                [label] => My Fruits
                [labels] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => My Fruits
                        [singular_name] => Fruit
                        [add_new] => Add New
                        [add_new_item] => Add New Fruit
                    )

                [description] => Fruits news and reviews
            )

)
```

I would like to turn in into the following array:

```
[
    { value: 'movies', label: 'Popular Movies' },
    { value: 'portfolio', label: 'New Portfolio Items' },
    { value: 'fruit', label: 'My Fruits' },
]
```

I'm using a foreach loop to create a new array:

```
// $post_types is the array 

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) { 
    $post_types_array['value'] = $post_type->label;
    $post_types_array['label'] = $post_type->name;
}
```

But it returns only the last item from the array. How is it possible to go trough each array row and create the desired array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not creating new array elements, you're just overwriting the values in the same array.

Also, you're getting the wrong elements from the `$post_type` object.

```
$post_types_array = [];
foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
    $post_types_array[] = [
        'value' => $post_type->name, 
        'label' => $post_type->labels->name
    ];
}
```

Comment: To make the code easier to read you probably want to have the array's properties on separate lines ...